# Coda-like experience for Ubuntu

Tags: sftp, web-development

I'm a web developer who's going to transition from using Mac OS X to Ubuntu.

I've been using Coda for some time, only because it makes web development easy. I know a full fledged app isn't available for Linux, but would like to know about apps that specialize in the same tasks that Coda offers.

I plan on switching to Vim for code editing, I'm extremely proficient and will install the Janus plugin and be good to go for editing code.

One thing that makes editing on Coda so amazing is its extremely good at SFTP, you can drag and drop files and/or folders from your local drive to the server. Also, you can edit code directly on the server. The problem here, is that using Vim I don't know of a way to edit code on a remote server, while using my own Vim settings and plugins. To solve this, I would like to know of a good SFTP client OR a good SFTP CLI. A CLI that could synchronize your files after a file has been modified would be perfect, but not necessary.

Now, one of the biggest and best features of Coda is its ability to view your databases. You get to create a database, create tables, add stuff, delete stuff and view the contents of the table (all this without writing a single SQL statement). I will admit that databases are my weak point, but is a very important part of my job. If there is a tool that specializes in databases would be perfect. I wouldn't prefer to use the command line for database stuff, but if there is a CLI for databases that I'm missing could potentially be useful.

So I guess I'm asking for two things. A tool that makes databases easier to visualize and a tool that assists in pushing my local code to a server.

Comment: you can try `sublime text` for coding and `Sublime SFTP`. But I don't know about db related app

Answer (score 1):

I have never used Coda, but if you are looking for a good and very extensible editor I can recomend SublimeText2.  The good thing about it is that it is cross platform (Win,Mac,Linux), so you can have the same dev setup no matter what OS you are using.  On top it is extendeable using Python, so it is very easy to write your own plugins.

Some other Editors I have used:

- BlueFish
- Geany
- Gedit/Gmate

these are the ones I know about, but I am sure there are hundreds more options.

Comment: That's cool, I will probably go back and forth between editors. The real question though, is an easy way to do SFTP and viewing databases.